# Google Apps Script - Email trigger not working outside domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a google form, went to response sheet - script editor - written script and activated a trigger to send email upon form submit, 'To' is as per the value entered in google form, 'cc' is by default 'raajesh@master-brains.com'.  This is not working.

But, when I modify the script as 'To' and 'Cc' to raajesh@master-brains.com, I am receiving the trigger email.  Why is it so?  Is it working only within my domain of master-brains.com?  What should I do to enable it for gmail / other domain accounts?

```js
function myFunction(onboard) { 
  var conNo = onboard.values[3]; 
  var conEmail = onboard.values[4]; 
  var subject = 'Welcome Onboard as Master-Brains Connector | '+conName; 
  var htmlBody = 'Greetings from Master-Brains!!'; 
  MailApp.sendEmail('raajesh@master-brains.com', subject, htmlBody, {'htmlBody':htmlBody, cc: 'raajesh@master-brains.com'}) 
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem sending the email to other domain accounts. Could you please share a sample of the code you're using, of course free of sensitive information?

Comment: function myFunction(onboard) {

  var conNo = onboard.values[3];
  var conEmail = onboard.values[4];
  
  var subject = 'Welcome Onboard as Master-Brains Connector | '+conName;
  
  var htmlBody = 'Greetings from Master-Brains!!';
  
  MailApp.sendEmail('raajesh@master-brains.com', subject, htmlBody, {'htmlBody':htmlBody, cc: 'raajesh@master-brains.com'})
  
}

Comment: The above script is working fine in getting trigger emails just because MailApp.SendEmail recipient email and CC is 'raajesh@master-brains.com'.

Comment: If I change MailApp.SendEmail recipient email to conEmail variable, emails are not getting triggered despite its a valid gmail ID.

Comment: Are you sure `conEmail` is getting assigned a valid email address?

Comment: Try using `Logger.log` to check that the email address is getting assigned correctly to `conEmail`.

Comment: Add the code to the question. Also include the textual errors that are logged in https://script.google.com